# Conversion Failed when selecting by case with date and using CONVERT

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm creating an asp.net page (2.0) and I'm having a terrible time with a query.

I'm working with dates, using convert(datetime, ExpirationDate) to format my dates, which are stored in the DB as varchars with the format 'yyyymmdd'.

Everything works fine until I try to replace null values with 'n/a', at which point I get:

```
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

I've tried

```
    case when expirationdate is not null then convert(datetime, expirationdate) 
else 'n/a' end as ExpirationDate
```

and

```
    case when expirationdate is null then 'n/a' 
else convert(datetime, expirationdate) end as ExpirationDate
```

I've even tried changing the value of the cell (in a databound gridview) programmatically with no luck.

I'll take any solution.

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and VS Professional 2008.

My full query is:

```
SELECT (firstname + ' ' + lastname) as userName, 
                EmployeeID, (SELECT Description FROM CMPRecords AS cm WHERE (CompentencyCode = co.CompetencyCode)) AS Competency, 
                convert(datetime, IssueDate) as IssueDate, 
                case when expirationdate is not null then CONVERT(datetime, expirationdate) else 'n/a' end as ExpirationDate FROM COMRecords AS co 
                WHERE (Username = @Username) 
                order by IssueDate Desc
```

Comment: Why not leave it null?  It cannot be a `datetime` or a `varchar`  you have to pick one of the two types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to say that sometimes you want a `datetime` and other times you want a `varchar`.  But you cannot do that.  In fact what's happening is that it sees the `datetime` value first and just assumes it should convert the `varchar` which fails.  You should either just convert it and if it is `null` you'll get a `null` `datetime`.  or leave it as `varchar` with a `null` check

```
CONVERT(datetime, expirationdate) as ExpirationDate
```

or

```
ISNULL(expirationdate, 'n/a') as ExpirationDate
```

It really depends on how you want to consume this value on which would work best.  I would recommend that you use the Convert, then populate the value to a `DateTime?` then do the formatting in your UI code.

```
string toDisplay = ExpirationDate == null ? "n/a" : ExpirationDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd")
```

Of course it would be best if you could change the database to properly store the value as a `datetime` instead of a `varchar`.

Comment: I see what you're saying here, and thank you for the help. How can I get the value of toDisplay into my DataGridView?

Comment: That depends on how you load the sql results into the `DataGridView`.  I'd recommend either showing us that code or maybe starting a new question.

Comment: I got it to work with the datetime conversion and the RowDataBound event. It was a bit of a pain figuring it out, because the cell held a value of '&nbsp;' but of course, it was displaying as a space. Checking if the value was '&nbsp;' and assigning it to 'n/a' in the RowDataBound event solved it.